# Undo operation in a reopened tab in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, undo

In XCode actually there is no closing and openning tabs and you can undo whenever you can even if you open another file and go back.

In Eclipse when you close a tab and then later re-open it you cannot undo of course.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't undo actions if you have closed the tab (which seems logic: if it's closed, it's not in use). A solution is to use the [local history](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-55.htm), which can be found when you:

```
Right-click the file in a navigation view and select Team > Show Local History.
```

you will see a different version of your file for **each save** you've made. From there you can compare, or restore it from a certain date.

*note:* You can change local history properties in:

```
Window ->Preferences > General > Workspace > Local History
```

(e.g.: if you want Eclipse to keep files longer or to keep more files)

Comment: It keeps a local history, so I think it is logically to use undo (maybe a different shortcut just for this) to go back in the local history. I do not know whether there is such shortcut or not but you know Eclipse is open-source. I am curious whether there are some plugin that does this or not.

Comment: looking at the [list of shortcuts](http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/Keyboard_shortcuts_(3.0).pdf), I see that you can navigate backward in history with Alt+Left, it will re-open the tab if you closed it, but only put the cursor where the change has been made, not undo-ing anything... I think the best solution is not to close the tabs you are using, but that can be hard on a big project. –

Comment: Yeah exactly. You know, Eclipse is not memory conservative at all. When I do that, it gets really slow.